# How to draw text in PDF context

Tags: ios, pdf

What's a right way to draw text in a PDF file? First, I tried:

```
NSString* string = @"Some Text";    
const char* chstr = [string UTF8String];
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(pdfConsumer, &pdfPageRect, NULL);
...
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(pdfContext, x, y, chstr, strlen(chstr));
...
CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
```

This worked but did not show unicode text correctly. Also the API CGContextShowTextAtPoint has been deprecated in iOS7. So I tried:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0]};
...
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
[string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withAttributes:textAttributes];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
...
CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
```

As suggested by some SO posts. But the app crashes on CGContextRelease(pdfContext). If I remove CGContextRelease(pdfContext), it does not draw anything in PDF. Am I missing anything?

** Additional information **

I figured out the crash in CGContextRelease happens only when NSString contains unicode text and here is the image of the call stack at the time of the crash. I even moved the test code of PDF generation in [AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions] but it still crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this! I have test it and it work.

//Ready to begin

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(tempPath, CGRectZero, nil);
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (doc, i); 
        //grab page i of the PDF
        CGRect bounds = [ReaderDocument boundsForPDFPage:page];

```
    //Create a new page
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(bounds, nil);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // flip context so page is right way up
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage (context, page); // draw the page into graphics context

    //Flip back right-side up
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -bounds.size.height);    

    //Draw text 
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill); // This is the default
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    CGRect newTextFrame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,30);
    [@"Your Text......" drawInRect:newTextFrame withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
CGPDFDocumentRelease(doc);
```